# React Router <NavLink> doesn't add active class

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

The `<NavLink>` doesn't add an active class on the corresponding page.
I checked the [React Router docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink), tried to add `/` after the path, use `activeClassName` and `activeStyle` `exact` attributes. 
For instance when I'm on the `http://localhost:3000/animals` page the `<NavLink to={"/animals"} >` doesn't have any "active" class. I can't see any changes in the console.
I believe that there is something simple, but I can't find a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a piece of code:

app.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
...  
import Header from "../header/header";
...
<Router>
 <main>
    <Header />
       <Switch>
         <Route path="/" exact>
           <HomePage />
         </Route>
         <Route path="/animals" exact>
           <AnimailsPage />
          </Route>
...
```

header.js:

```
import React from "react";
import Menu from "../menu/menu";
...
<nav>
  ...
  <Menu />
  ...
</nav>
...
```

menu js:

```
import React from "react";
import {NavLink} from "react-router-dom";

  const Menu = () => {
    return(
      <ul className={"menu"}>
        <li className={"menu__item"}>
          <NavLink to={"/"} className={"menu__link"} exact>All</NavLink>
        </li>
        <li className={"menu__item"}>
          <NavLink to={"/animals"} className={"menu__link"}>Animals</NavLink>
        </li>
        ...
```

And here are packages versions:

> react 16.11.0
>
> react-route 5.1.2
>
> react-router-dom 5.1.2

Comment: In your `<NavLink to={"/"} className={"menu__link"} exact>All</NavLink>`, add the `activeClassName` attribute, like: `<NavLink to={"/"} className={"menu__link"} exact activeClassName='active'>All</NavLink>`

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I can see only `menu__link` in the inspecotor.